# Does An Object Have "Children"

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I just want to know if the object in question, has any sub-objects within it or not.
Do I really have to do THIS:

```
public static function getLength(o:Object):bool
{
  for (var item:* in o)
    if (item != "mx_internal_uid")
        return true;
  return false;
}
```

Isn't there some way to say SOMETHING LIKE: Object.hasChildren();
OR EVEN Object.childCount();

The Object in question does NOT extend the DisplayObjectContainer.  It is just something like:

```
var Ob:Object;
Ob.SomeProp="xxx";
Ob.SomeOtherProp="zzz";
```

How can I know how many "entries" there are in the object. (in this case 2).

In other words, how does "for (var item:* in Ob)" know when to stop.
???

Comment: you don't need to know when to stop, you just need to count how man times that for looped.

Answer (score 5):

A good class to inspect objects is the flex built in ***ObjectUtil***. I think what you're trying to achieve would be done by using (*obj* is the object to analyze):

> ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(obj).properties.length

But ***ObjectUtil.getClassInfo*** would be a good place too look if you're trying to analyze an object, it returns a lot of information (read more on [LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#getClassInfo%28%29)).

It also has a function to check if a variable is a simple one - ***ObjectUtil.isSimple***

Comment: awesome! I didn't know about this one. Pretty Handy ! +1 
Haven't used the flex framework in a while

Answer (score 0):

By object you mean the Object class, hence counting the properties, or the object on the displaylist, if the latter, that objects surely extends DisplayObjectContainer wich has the numChildren property

Comment: No, I can't count on the object being an extension of DisplayObjectContainer.

Answer (score 0):

As kajyr says, if it's a DisplayObjectContainer you can check for numChildren.

If you want to check if a generic objects contains simple properties ( primitives like Number,int, uint, String, Boolean ) or complex properties (subObjects, instances of some class ) that you might regards as children to that generic object, you do the following:

```
var testObj:Object = {id:1,name:'DumDum'};
var testObj2:Object = {id:2,name:'NumNum',data:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],somethingComplex:{firstName:'Num',lastName:'Num'}};

trace(isSimple(testObj).length == 0);//prints true
trace(isSimple(testObj2).length == 0);//prints false
trace(isSimple(testObj2));

function isSimple(obj:*):Array{
    var complex:Array = [];
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(!(obj[prop] is String || obj[prop] is int || obj[prop] is uint || obj[prop] is Number  || obj[prop] is Boolean)) 
            complex.push({prop: obj[prop]});
    }
    return complex;
}
```

If you want to get the number of members (variables associated with an object), that is easy enough to get:

```
var Ob:Object = {};
Ob.SomeProp="xxx";
Ob.SomeOtherProp="zzz";

trace(getMembersNum(Ob));//prints 2

function getMembersNum(obj:*):int{
    var result:int = 0;
    for(var prop in obj) result++;
    return result;
}
```

You would write this in your utility package/class maybe like this:

```
public static function get numMembers(obj:*):int{
    var result:int = 0;
    for(var prop in obj) result++;
    return result;
}
```

HTH